# How to chain if else elegantly

Tags: python

I have an odd piece of code.  It's smelly but I can't think of way to make if more clear.

What I'm trying to do is remove the largest item from either the tail of the left list or the head of right list.  I ended up with this code.

```
if not left:
  right.pop(0)
elif not right:
  left.pop(-1):
elif len(left[-1]) < len(right[0]):
  right.pop(0)
else:
  left.pop(-1)
```

The bodies of the conditions are exact duplicates of each other, yuck.

Is there an elegant way to restructure this code to minimize duplication?

Comment: Sorry for the crappy title, feel free to improve it.

Comment: it sounds like you need [this module](http://entrian.com/goto/)  (just kidding)

Comment: Repeating one liners doesn't seem too bad of "repetition" for me.  I like your code more than all alternate forms posted so far.

Comment: I find nothing wrong with your code as presented - it clearly separates the four cases you consider, and you can add comments within each branch to explain what each case means. If you nest it, then you are blurring the logic in favor of a false notion of elegance. If your code needed to "short circuit" for performance reasons, I would agree, but it does not need to short circuit. Code is written once and read hundreds of times - I would value the code as you wrote it much more.

Comment: @AndréCaron, indeed, I posted some of that code, but to be honest, I agree :)

Comment: @Arrieta It looks like the answer should be _"No that code cannot be made more elegant"_.  Anyone brave enough to post it?

Comment: @deft_code I think not everything can be made elegant. The code is not elegant, but making it elegant would trump its function. For example, a basket of fries with melted cheddar is hardly elegant, but it is delicious ;)

Answer (score 6):

Chain your conditions instead, and eliminate redundant terms.

```
if (not left) or (right and (len(left[-1]) < len(right[0]))):
  right.pop(0)
else:
  left.pop(-1)
```

Comment: That seems harder to read than the original code, because I have to stop and think about what that nested boolean logic means.

Comment: @Greg: You aren't wrong, but there must be nesting *somewhere*.

Answer (score 4):

Would this work?

```
>>> left_len = len(left[-1]) if left else -1
>>> right_len = len(right[0]) if right else -1
>>> right.pop(0) if right_len > left_len else left.pop(-1)
9
```

The behavior is a little different, in that if `not left and not right`, `left.pop(-1)` instead of `right.pop(0)`. But then, it's an error either way...

Comment: I thought the same, but it should be more like `else -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Some hacky approach (that coincides to be a bit more generic as well because it can scale to more than 2 lists):

```
_, lst, i = max((len(lst[i]), lst,i) for lst,i 
                in ((left, -1), (right, 0)) if lst)
lst.pop(i)
```

Comment: +1 for sheer inscrutability. :) But what about this? `lst, i = max(((lst, i) for lst, i in ((left, -1), (right, 0)) if lst), key=lambda x: len(x[0][x[1]]))`

Comment: @senderle: Actually I thought the very same! But when I tried it out, it was longer, so I didn't want to add it :P

Answer (score 1):

```
left_tail_size = len(left[-1]) if left else 0
right_head_size = len(right[0]) if right else 0

if left_tail_size >= right_head_size:
  left.pop(-1)
else:
  right.pop(0)
```

Comment: Should be `else -1` but apart from that bug it's pretty much the same as senderle's answer.